# yii2:my dataprovider not sort true

Tags: yii2

I have dataprovider to get 9 posts order by create time but my order and limit  not worked

```
$dataProviderlatenew=new ActiveDataProvider([
         'query'=>Post::find()->limit(9)->orderBy('create_time DESC'),
         'sort' => [
         'defaultOrder' => [
                 'create_time' => SORT_DESC,
             ],
          ],
         ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that if pagination is not false the limit is managed  automatically and not using the limit you have in query  ..  so for the order

```
$dataProviderlatenew=new ActiveDataProvider([
     'query'=>Post::find(),
     'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => [ 'create_time' => SORT_DESC, ],
     ],
]);
```

otherwise set aproper pagination    (so you can use limit(9) ) and don't impose an order in select and a default order in dataProvider (is a non sense)

eg:

```
    $dataProviderlatenew=new ActiveDataProvider([
     'query'=>Post::find(),
     'pagination' =>['pagesize' =>9],
     'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => [ 'create_time' => SORT_DESC, ],
     ],
]);
```

or

```
    $dataProviderlatenew=new ActiveDataProvider([
     'query'=>Post::find()->limit(9),
     'pagination' =>false,
     'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => [ 'create_time' => SORT_DESC, ],
     ],
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
$dataProviderlatenew=new ActiveDataProvider([
 'query'=>Post::find(),
 'pagination'=>['pagesize'=>9],
 'sort' => [
      'defaultOrder' => [ 'create_time' => SORT_DESC],
    ],
 ]);
```

Refer : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html